# enclose maximum no of point inside square of length l

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, geometry

What would be the algorithm for given problem statement?
Given n points in 2D plain you need to find square(sides parallel to axes) of side length l which cover maximum no of points from given n points?

output should be bottom-left coordinate of square and no of point it enclose.

Comment: Whats stopping you from covering all the points?

Comment: square of given length l may or may not cover all points.It's a given length which stopping me from covering all points.

Comment: So what should be the output?

Comment: output should be bottom-left coordinate of square and no of point it enclose.

Comment: For giving coordiantes as output we need to know the coordinates of points.

Comment: yes we have coordinate of n points in form of (x,y)

Comment: How only giving coordinates of bottom-left corner of the square would define the square?

Comment: sides of square are parallel to axes

Comment: Then add that to the question too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A brute force algorithm based on the idea that any solution can be moved upwards and to the right until the lower and left sides contain a point:

for all pairs of points try to construct a square with side length l with one point of the pair on the left side and one points of the pair on the lower side. If this is possible count the number of points in it. Keep the square with the maximal number of points.